# Why R is not being printed ? why the output is PQST?

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception, java-15

Here's my code. Here PQRST should be the output but R is not printed. I don't understand why ?

```
class Validator{
    public int[] studentId = { 101, 102, 103 };

    public void validateStudent(int id) {
        try {
            for (int index = 0; index <= studentId.length; index++) {
                if (id == studentId[index])
                    System.out.println("P");
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Q");
        }
    }
}


public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        try {
            validator.validateStudent(101);
            System.out.print("R");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("S");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("T");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *PQRST should be the output*  That is not possible with the code as shown - R and S are mutually exclusive, since if R is printed, there's nothing following that can throw the out-of-bounds exception to print S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the validateStudent method ends with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception`, and therefore the `System.out.print ("R");` statement does not execute. When the exception happens.

I would probably try to solve this problem a little differently and not with exceptions, which in my opinion are quite complicated in terms of logic and processing. It simply slows down the program that could be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Because you exceed the length of the array. This

```
for (int index = 0; index <= studentId.length; index++) {
```

should be

```
for (int index = 0; index < studentId.length; index++) {
```

But then `S` will not be printed (because it won't throw an `Exception`).

Today is an ***excellent*** day to learn how to use a debugger.